# How to save cropped image?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I get this values when i crop image:

```
h
:
408.43636363636364
w
:
726.1090909090909
x
:
233.89090909090908
x2
:
960
y
:
75.05454545454545
y2
:
483.49090909090904
```

How can i save image with those parameres?

```
  Image::make($image->getRealPath())->save($path. '/' .$filename);
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: How are you getting the values?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/2511/ there

Comment: I'm assuming you're also using Intervention Image?

Comment: yes im using Intervetion image

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `crop()` that comes with Intervetion image: http://image.intervention.io/api/crop

Assuming that you're submitting the values as the are in your example you would do something like:

```
Image::make($image->getRealPath())
->crop($request->input('w'), $request->input('h'), $request->input('w'), $request->input('h'))
->save($path. '/' .$filename);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: if i do like this i will get only croped image by size not real part of pic what i cropped

Comment: @None How do you figure that?

Comment: i get this error crop() accepts only integer values as argument 1.

Comment: @None In that case you'll need to cast your values to integers e.g. `(int)$request->input('w')`.